# JTextfield.getText().equals() method not working

Tags: netbeans, jtextfield

I am trying to check whether a jTextfield is empty using the following code, then display an error dialog if it is.

```
if(sproductname.getText().equals("")){
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"One         or more fields is empty","Empty       field",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
     }
```

The method is in actionperformed and should be executed when I press a button but in this case nothing happens. What could be wrong is such a small block of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (sproductname.getText().isEmpty()){
    ...
}
```

Comment: It´s a common problem with method, each one string have no characters (length = 0) then java assumes they don´t match.

Answer (score 0):

Ur code didn't working because basic value for object type String is null. Not empty string. All object type in Java have basic value == null.

Comment: Oh awesome. Thanks y'all:-)